# Cómo usar una paleta de colores con GEOM_POINT sobre un mapa?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Estoy en aprendizaje de mapas con ggplot. En este momento intento darle una paleta de colores a los puntos (estaciones) ubicadas dentro de un mapa, pero no lo he logrado. Copio codigo y resultados

```
###ubicacion_de_estaciones
Colom_estac = ne_states(country = "Colombia", returnclass = 'sf')

##ubicacion_estac tiene dos columnas de longitud y latitud donde estan ubicadas las estaciones
```

En otro df tengo para cada una de las estaciones el porcentaje de cambio que varia entre -100 y 1000, y debo graficar los puntos en el mapa con una paleta de colores

hasta ahora solo he podido graficar los puntos dentro de mi mapa, pero no se como agregarlos con el porcentaje de cambio y su correspondiente paleta de colores

```
    ggplot(data=Colom_estac)+
      geom_sf()+  
      geom_point(ubicacion_estac, mapping = aes(x=longitude,y=latitude), shape = 23, 
      fill = "darkred" )+
      ggtitle(str_c(indices[[1]]," percchange(nay - normales)"))
```

[image: estaciones de colombia]

Comment: Bienvenido alberto, mira, si quieres variar el color en función a cierto dato, lo que necesitas es "mapear" ese dato a  la dimensión estética `fill`, ahora `fill` esta fijo en el color rojo oscuro, debería intentar algo así: `aes(x=longitude,y=latitude, fill=pocentaje)` dónde `porcentaje` será la variable que mencionas.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, mi error era que tenia dos df diferentes, y debo tener los datos en un solo df, para este caso ubicacion_estac